# Android Studio: 'title' in FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a Android Application atm.. But I need some help, I want my fragment to have a little title in the left top corner (I know I can style text myself, but still.. I'd like to know what the property of this particular property is). Under here is a picture of what I want.

[image]

I want the property of the title where the red line is under. It's probably something with the TextAppreance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK this image is not a fragment but a `ListView` which has his `Headers` define

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show title at the top left in the FrameLayout, you can use this.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="your_title"
            android:textColor="#2d8595"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was asking a bit of a weird question.